# How to post serialize object and multiple images in ajax post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to post the values to the controller via ajax post. Here my problem is I am using Serialize method to post the form values. I have to send Images as well. How can I send images and form data and what should be the controller method that accepts both files and model values?

I am getting all the text values like this

```
var files = $("#formid").serialize();
```

I am getting images like this

```
 var form1Data = new FormData();
 var totalFiles = document.getElementById("files").files.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
        var file = document.getElementById("files").files[i];
        form1Data.append("files", file);
  }
```

In ajax call I have to send both files and formdata. How to send in the ajax call

```
 $.ajax(
         {
             url: "/Home/PostanAd/",
             type: "POST",                  
             data: { form1Data: form1Data, files: files },
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
         });
```

can some one please suggest the answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to append whole set of model to formdata and obtain it in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

```
var formData = new FormData();
```

//For each your form inputs use this line

```
form_data.append("name1", $("#id1").val());
```

//Now Add All Images to Form Data object

```
var totalFiles = document.getElementById("files").files.length;
for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
    var file = document.getElementById("files").files[i];
    formData.append("files[]", file);  //Use [] to add multiple.
}
```

//Then just make simple ajax call with data : formData   only

```
$.ajax(
            {
                url: "/Home/PostanAd/",
                type: "POST",

                data: formdata,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
```

Comment: how can i get values in the model ? or should i use httppostedfilebase??

Comment: you can use $_FILE  to read uploaded files. and run for loop for accessing all files

Comment: @user3518928, Did you even look at the link I gave you above? Its just `var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));` and `data: formdata,` (one line of code serializes all you form values and all the files!)